# LIKE clause not returning when comparing numbers with single quotes

Tags: mysql

I have a query contains a field `transaction_id` and data type integer.

In the `WHERE` condition of below query I have `LIKE` operator, in this case if I give `transaction_id  LIKE '00412552'` I am not getting data.

Suppose if I give `transaction_id LIKE 00412552` then I am getting data.

I think it is not taking string type as operator, please suggest what is the problem.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT crt.carton_no, 
                 crt.shipment_ref_no,
                 crt.put_away_location,
                 crt.item_category,
                 crt.total_quantity     
            FROM carton crt 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN pick_list pl 
              ON (crt.carton_no = pl.carton_no AND 
                 crt.shipment_ref_no = pl.shipment_ref_no) 
           WHERE pl.transaction_id LIKE '00412552'
```

Comment: I think your first example should be `in '00412552'`? You need to combine the `in` operator with brackets: `in ('00412552')` even if there is just one element. It takes Strings without problems.

Comment: if transaction_id is an integer then why not use = (equal) operator

Comment: Hi sonali and dognose the operator like operator.   where transaction_id LIKE '00412552'

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is stored as an integer without leading zeroes so why would you expect that when cast to string it would match a string beginning `00`?

Comment: i need to give like this where transaction_id LIKE '00412552'.But it is not working.

Comment: the column transaction_id contains values with leading zeros?

Comment: @vissubabu [**Kindly consider checking my answer as the right answer if it worked for you, see here how.**](http://stackoverflow.com/about)